# rollback did not happen with save transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three questions.

First can someone tell me why rollback of the save transaction did not happen. I had entered an error 1/0 after delete #t2 in second block of Try..Catch statement.

Second if for example procedure T1 calls procedure T2 and there is a error in T2 procedure will the outer transaction be rolled back completely even in case I use Xact_Abort off.Can I commit the transaction.

My third question is it possible to commit only the save transaction and not the entire transaction.

```
if exists(select * from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where TABLE_NAME    like '%#T1%')
begin
    drop table #t1
    drop table #t2
    drop table #t3
    drop table #t4
    drop table #t5
end

CREATE TABLE #T1(C int);
CREATE TABLE #T2(C int);
CREATE TABLE #T3(C int);
CREATE TABLE #T4(C int);
CREATE TABLE #T5(C int);

INSERT INTO #T1 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T2 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T3 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T4 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T5 SELECT 1;
begin transaction

begin try
delete #t1
    --step 1
end try

begin catch
rollback transaction
end catch

if @@ERROR = 0 
begin
save transaction t1
end

begin try
delete #t2      ---step 2
select 1/0
end try

begin catch
rollback transaction t1
commit transaction
end catch
```

Comment: Rollback tran t1 will rollback everything till save t1. Commit after rollback t1 will commit everything before save t1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure out the reason why rollback for t1 transaction looked like it was not happening that's because I was saving transaction after deleting  table #t1 and so it was showing null values.its working fine without save transaction. Thanks